# Xamarin Keyboard Flickers When Setting Entry Focus

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have three entry fields but the tab order of the fields is dependent upon certain conditions. The issue I have is if I set the focus from the code the keyboard disappears then reappears.

I created a simple application, for testing purpose, with just three fields and set focus in the code. The keyboard flickers.

If I set ReturnType="Next" and set the TabIndex for each control there is no keyboard flicker, however, I don't have a set tab order so I need to set focus from the code. I tried changing the .TabIndex and .IsTabStop from the code and it works for subsequent events not for the initial Entry_Completed event.

Is there a way for me control the Android keyboard manually so I explicitly tell it stay on the screen on go away?

```
<StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="one" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="0" Placeholder="One" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
        <Entry x:Name="two" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="1" Placeholder="Two" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
        <Entry x:Name="three" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="2" Placeholder="Three" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

```
private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == one)
                three.Focus();
            else if (sender == two)
                one.Focus();
            else if (sender == three)
                two.Focus();
        }
```

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62B21.gif)

Comment: I tested the code you provided, and when I clicked enter, the keyboard did not flicker, and the focus was switched normally.

Comment: Please refer to the 'Demo' link I added. The problem is it briefly stops in entry two before going to three, which looks very janky. That's if I include ReturnType="Next", if I remove that it goes straight from entry one to entry three but the keyboard flicker occurs.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I found that the reason for the problem is that you have a numeric keyboard when you jump from the first Entry to the third Entry.

I avoided this problem by modifying the TabIndex.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="one" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="0" Placeholder="One" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
    <Entry x:Name="two" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="2" Placeholder="Two" Completed="Entry_Completed" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
    <Entry x:Name="three" ReturnType="Next" TabIndex="1" Placeholder="Three" Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Has the problem been resolved？

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my original post. I created this simple project as a test but there is no set tab order for my Entry controls. The tab order is dependent upon selections that the user makes. Your solution works if there's a set tab order but I don't have one.

Comment: In theory, no matter how you choose this way of writing, you will not have the above problem.

Comment: Just avoid the numeric keypad when switching focus.